# How to create a interval (timer) within loop to SortAlgorithm Visualization

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I want to create a program that shows the steps of sorting algorithms, like that:

https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg

My problem is that I can't create a interval timer to see the steps of my sorting algorithms

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var array = [10, 150, 17, 200, 300, 110, 400, 260, 105, 157, 180, 208, 400, 122, 40, 266, 123];

drawnLines(array);

function init() {
  bubbleSort(array);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500)
  drawnLines(array);
}

function drawnLines(array) {
  let width;
  let position = 5;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    width = array[i];
    ctx.fillRect(position, 5, 10, width);
    ctx.stroke();
    position += 20;
  }
};

function bubbleSort(array) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      setTimeout(function(y) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
          var temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[i + 1];
          array[i + 1] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
        console.log(array[i])
      }, i * 2000, i)
    }
  } while (swapped);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sketch-js@1.1.3/js/sketch.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Bubble Sort</button>
```

```
///output:
    123
(2) 123
(3) 123
(4) 123
...
(only the last number in my array)
```

Comment: you should use `y` instead of `i`

Comment: yes, since you went to the trouble of passing the parameter, or you could declare `i` with `let` instead of `var` and avoid the parameter entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) with few modifications:

- `yield` in your sorting algo
- `next()` then `await sleepSomeTime` in `init`

```js
  
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var array = [10, 150, 17, 200, 300, 110, 400, 260, 105, 157, 180, 208, 400, 122, 40, 266, 123];

drawnLines(array);
function sleep(ts){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(resolve, ts)
  })
}
async function init() {
  const it = bubbleSort(array)
  let result = it.next()
  while (!result.done) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500)
    drawnLines(array);
    result = it.next();
    await sleep(100)
  }
  console.log('finished!')
}

function drawnLines(array) {
  let width;
  let position = 5;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    width = array[i];
    ctx.fillRect(position, 5, 10, width);
    ctx.stroke();
    position += 20;
  }
};

function* bubbleSort(array) {
  var swapped;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        array[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
        yield
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sketch-js@1.1.3/js/sketch.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Bubble Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the async generator along with the async processing function. You implement your logic in the processing function while generator does the timing and provides you with array indexes *a*, *b*, and Boolean *swapped*.

```js
var array = [10, 150, 17, 266, 123, 300];
async function* bubbleSortGenerator(array) {
  var arr = array.slice(0);
  var straight = false;
  const end = arr.length - 1;
  var iterations = 0;
  while (!straight) {
    straight = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < end - iterations; i++) {
      var swapped = false;
      if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
        const tmp = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
        swapped = true;
        straight = false;
      }
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200)); //here
      yield {
        a: i,
        b: i + 1,
        swapped: swapped
      };
    }
    iterations++;
  }
  yield arr;
}
async function process() {
  for await (const val of bubbleSortGenerator(array)) {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
process();
```